# Как сделать так что бы меню не закрывалось по клику на него?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так что бы меню, не закрывалось при клике на пункты .sub-menu? А закрывалось по клику на ссылку.

```js
var ACTIVE = 'mega-menu-active';
$(".main-navigation > .maga-menu__list > .mega-menu__item").on('click', function() {
  let clickedElementIsActive = $(this).hasClass(ACTIVE);
  $(".main-navigation > .maga-menu__list > .mega-menu__item").removeClass(ACTIVE);

  clickedElementIsActive ? $(this).removeClass(ACTIVE) : $(this).addClass(ACTIVE);
});
```

```css
.maga-menu__list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.mega-menu__link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.mega-menu-active .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="main-navigation">
  <ul class="maga-menu__list">
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a class="mega-menu__link">menu1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a class="mega-menu__link">menu2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a class="mega-menu__link">menu3</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить проверку цели клика. Если клик не на ссылке, то возвращаем `void`, иначе добавляем/убираем класс `mega-menu-active` в родительском элементе.

```js
const ACTIVE = 'mega-menu-active';
$(".main-navigation > .maga-menu__list > .mega-menu__item > a").on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target !== this) return;
  $(this.parentNode).toggleClass(ACTIVE);
});
```

```css
.maga-menu__list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.mega-menu__link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.mega-menu-active .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <ul class="maga-menu__list">
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a class="mega-menu__link">menu1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a class="mega-menu__link">menu2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a class="mega-menu__link">menu3</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Чтобы открыть можно было только одно меню, можно пробегать по меню и если есть откртое, закрывать.

```js
const ACTIVE = 'mega-menu-active';
$(".main-navigation > .maga-menu__list > .mega-menu__item > a").on('click', function(event) {
  const link = this;
  if (event.target !== link) return;
  $('.main-navigation > .maga-menu__list > .mega-menu__item').each(function() {
    if (this == link.parentNode) return;
    $(this).removeClass(ACTIVE);
  });
  $(link.parentNode).toggleClass(ACTIVE);
});
```

```css
.maga-menu__list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.mega-menu__link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.mega-menu-active .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <ul class="maga-menu__list">
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a class="mega-menu__link">menu1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a class="mega-menu__link">menu2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a class="mega-menu__link">menu3</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
        <li>sub-menu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: А как сделать так, что бы при этом, только одно меню можно было открыть?

Comment: @КонстантинЖевжик дополнил ответ. Старайтесь решать такие задачи сами. В сети полно книг, статей, туториалов. Кто ищет, тот найдет.